# Matlab Chi^2 Goodness of fit test for specified mean

Tags: matlab, statistics, goodness-of-fit

I would like to perform a chi^2 goodness of fit test in Matlab and have found the function h = chi2gof(x) to do almost what I want. The only issue is that I want to perform the fit about a proposed mean and not the mean that chi2gof automatically estimates from the data.

Comment: I think that you may be able to do this if are able to specify more information than just your own mean estimate. You'd need to provide the CDF, and any parameters of the particular distribution, e.g., mean and std. dev. for a normal distribution. See [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html#expand_panel_heading_d124e174999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer starting with the point that seems to generate confusion:

*The only issue is that I want to perform the fit about a proposed mean and not the mean that chi2gof automatically estimates from the data.*

**1.- `chi2gof` does not estimate a mean from data**

`chi2gof` estimates how likely is the supplied data to be the pdf **that you tell** `chi2gof` it may be.

You supply the likely pdf therefore you supply the mean and other statistical moments that the data may or may not show.

**2.- By default normal aka Gaussian**

If you input just `x` the data

```
h=chi2gof(x)
```

`chi2gof` assumes it's a normal distribution with significance level `p = 0.05`

If the data is generated as normal with `mean=100` and `sigma=1` then `chi2gof` solves

**is `x` normal with significance level aka p=0.05 ?**

To change the significance level

```
h=chi2gof(x,'Alpha',.01)
```

The default significance level by default is 0.05 .

There has been some initiative to change such 0.05 default value down to 0.005 but it backfired, the experts casting further doubt on being able at all to pontificate around a bare threshold, details in article [Moving to a world beyond p<0.05, authors:
R.L.Wasserstein,A.L.Schirm, N.A.Lazar Mar20th 2019 American Statistician](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2019.1583913) .

**3.- `Alpha` IS NOT mean(x)**

`Alpha` is a threshold for significance level `p`.

`Alpha=0.01` means the probability of errors or false positives being 1 in 100 samples, on average.

**4.- To change the reference distribution in chi2gof use field CDF**

First define the specific distribution with the particular mean you are aiming at, for instance

```
pd = fitdist(x,'Weibull');
```

and then use pd in `chi2gof`

```
h = chi2gof(x,'CDF',pd)
```

The complete `chi2gof` help file is available online here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html

Comment: When refering to "estimate of mean from data" I was referencing the matlab help page which you also linked:

"h = chi2gof(x) returns a test decision for the null hypothesis that the data in vector x comes from a normal distribution with a mean and variance estimated from x".

A proposed solution worked which was also found in the matlap help being h = chi2gof(x,'cdf',{@normcdf, mean, std}

Comment: yes, and in @normcdf you can put any other distribution, besides normal. Does the CDF field work and does it solve your question?